# Turn Groups of Rows into One Row with Many Cols

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How can I turn a dataframe that looks like this :

```
  c1 c2 c3 c4
  1  1  1  1
  1  1  2  2
  1  2  1  3
  1  2  2  4
  2  1  1  5
  2  2  2  6
```

into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  c3 c11_c21_c4 c11_c22_c4 c12_c21_c4 c12_c22_c4
  1  1          3          5          null
  2  2          4          null       6
```

That is, I want to group by c3, then I want all of the combinations of column values for c1 and c2 to become columns themselves with the corresponding value of c4 underneath them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll end up with a multiindex for your column names, but you can use `pd.pivot_table`:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'c3', columns = ['c1', 'c2'], values = 'c4')

print(df2)
c1    1         2     
c2    1    2    1    2
c3                    
1   1.0  3.0  5.0  NaN
2   2.0  4.0  NaN  6.0
```

edit: and you can make it look exactly like your output by collapsing your 2-dimensional column labels, and resetting your index so that 'c3' is a normal column

```
df2.columns = [f"c1{x[0]}_c2{x[1]}_c4" for x in df2.columns]
df2.reset_index(inplace = True)

print(df2)
   c3  c11_c21_c4  c11_c22_c4  c12_c21_c4  c12_c22_c4
0   1         1.0         3.0         5.0         NaN
1   2         2.0         4.0         NaN         6.0
```